# calculate different slopes on the same curve with linear regression?

Tags: r, linear-regression

i need help linear regression in R, i have a data set that consist of
time, oxygen(mg/l), light, data Ok(good data=1, bad=0[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dooXq.png)). I have been measuring oxygen with 10 different light intensities. i want to calculate the slope for each light group. The graph would be time on the x-axis and oxygen on the y-axis,and then i want the slopes for each time i have changed the light intensities on the curve. im very new with R, and i use R-studio.

Comment: Please read [mcve] and in particular provide the input in a form that anyone can simply copy and paste into their R session such as using `dput(x)`.   Also show your best code attempt.

Comment: im sorry, i want to group the data, and find the slope for each group. groups is based on light intensities, where i have measured oxygen (mg/l) over time. 10 different light intensities.

Comment: Here's a blog post with detailed examples of running regressions by group and plotting the results: https://drsimonj.svbtle.com/running-a-model-on-separate-groups